# IOS: App crash installing Apollo library on real device (dyld[561]: Library not loaded: @rpath/ApolloAPI.framework/ApolloAPI) XCode 14.1

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, apollo, swift-package-manager

We are migrating from cocoapods to SPM and we have a crash when install on a real device after update to Apollo to 1.0.6. We're using xCode 14.1

#### Project structure

The project is a workspace that contains the following targets:

- One main target
- CocoaPod framework **target A** that contains the apollo schema, operations, etc
- CocoaPod framework **target B** with all the networking and the integration with the Apollo client.

Also right now contains a mix of cocoapods and SPM dependencies. (We're migrating from cocoapods to SPM)

#### Apollo configuration

- The **target A** add ApolloAPI using SPM through Xcode.
  [image]
  [image]
- The **target B** add Apollo and ApolloTestSupport dependencies and also has a dependency with the target A.
  [image]

#### Issue observed

Everything works fine on the simulator but when try to install the app on a real device we get the following crash:
[image]

Anyone had similar issue? Maybe something wrong in the configuration? Any help is much appreciated.

Trying to install the app in a real device. It works as expected on the simulator

Comment: Can you try a clean build and see if it works on Simulator? //Removing derived data.

Comment: @vignesh On the simulator works fine. The problem is on the real device